# Display Custom Post template name in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I need to display custom post template name.
Actually i want to load different css for each custom post template.
For this i need the custom post template name but i cant find it anyhow.
Here is the structure of my directory.

```
index.php
single.php
header.php
footer.php
fullpage-post.php // This is custom template
two-column-right-menu-post.php
two-column-left-menu-post.php
```

Now in header i want something link this

```
if($custom_template->name == 'two-column-right-menu-post'){
?> <link href = 'style.php'> <?php
}else{
?> <link href = 'style1.php'> <?php
}
```

How can i achieve this. I googled around and could not find the solution.

Comment: you want to get  post detail on page  or want to enter posts from the front end

Comment: to call the posts  you can use  query_post('showposts'); while(have_posts()):the_post();  the_title() endwhile; wp_reset_query();

Comment: displaying post is not a problem i am attaching a template to specific post. and in the header i want a condition if that template is attached load specific style sheet that belongs to that template.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="your stylesheep.css"> include this way your style sheet  and at the  top  after <?php  add   <?php /* Template Name:myposttemplate*/ ?> it will show in admin when you will select the  template for  page

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [get_page_template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_template).

A side not you are including css wrong. You should not use `<link>` to include styles but you should use [wp_enqueue_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/wp_enqueue_style), this allows stuff like caching and minify.
Roughly the same goes for javascript which has [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

A good tutorial about it: http://halfelf.org/2012/jquery-why-u-no-enqueued/

Comment: this does not seem to help

Answer (score 0):

After digging into wordpress database i have found a solution for this. Here is it.

AS i have added custom-post-template plugin in my application and able to create and attach templates to post i found this solution.

```
$post_meta      =   get_post_meta($post->ID);
$post_template  =   $post_meta['custom_post_template'][0];
```

This will return me the name of post-template. And now conditions can be used like this

```
if($post_template == 'two-column-right-menu-post.php'){
    ?> <link href = 'style.php'> <?php
}else{
    ?> <link href = 'style1.php'> <?php
}
```

Or this is better solution

```
$post_template  =   get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_post_template', true );
```